# Generating big sitemap, using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I've made a simple `sitemap.php`, which generates `sitemap.xml`, using a `sitemap.xsl` theme - it's populated by a MySQL database.

Everything works, but I have 4,000,000+ products, and it takes really long time, and a lot of memory, to generate it.

Does anyone have an idea, how I can make it with a better performance?

---

**sitemap.php:** http://pastebin.com/gM3Sa4BS

**sitemap.xsl:** http://pastebin.com/WVuuwT99

Comment: You should post this on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Does the product list change frequently? Can you just generate the diffs?

Comment: Actually, the products links stays the same, so basically, I need to generate only the newly added products. I'm just not sure how I can achieve that.

Comment: Set a flag in your product table to indicate whether it has been generated before.  Maybe even indicate which sitemap file is a part of.  Then you will only regenerate up to 25,000 links for the newest sitemap file.